# In Linux Fedora, How can I select files to move by time interval

Tags: linux, files, find, timestamps

How can I select and move files that were written in a specified time interval, such as 1530 to 1730 local time on a recent date?

Background: I use Linux Fedora 12, and I have made my first, and long overdue, back up of my home directory to an external hard drive preparatory to upgrading to the latest Fedora release, on a new computer, using **rsync**. Unfortunately, although I did a lot of dry runs to check that it would work correctly, I misunderstood the destination file specification and now have all my backed up files (60000 files in 32Gb) mixed in with the original disk contents instead of in their own separate directory. So I would like to select all the files saved during the hour that the backup took, and move them to another directory.

Comment: Was the backup done in such a way that all file modification times were changed? Normally, `rsync` would preserve original modification times, making it impossible to find the right files in this way.

Comment: @grebneke, in this case, you can use the ctime, though not on directories.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas - great, it's worth a try. I checked some of my own rsync backups and ctime actually seems to be correct also for directories.

Comment: @grebneke, the ctime will be updated for directories that were already there but have been added new files

Comment: @StephaneChazelas - I checked some directories that haven't been touched for years, including their content, and the ctime for the directories is exactly when they were recently rsynced. I never overwrite backups but write new ones with `--hard-links` to previous versions. Any way, it's the best suggestion to try for OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As suggested by [Stephane Chazelas](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/22565/stephane-chazelas), you could use `find` and check for [ctime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stat_%28system_call%29#ctime).

Assuming the backup was initiated 200 minutes ago, and terminated 100 minutes ago, this will find anything with a ctime in that interval:

```
find -cmin -200 -cmin +100
```

Do your dry-runs and if it looks good, construct your restauration based on that.

**Update:**

A general starting point for moving your files could look like (remove `echo` to `mv` for real):

```
find source --mindepth 1 -cmin -200 -cmin +100 -exec echo mv -v "{}" target \;
```

where `--mindepth 1` helps avoid `source` itself being moved (in that case you could just `mv source target`), and `"{}"` makes `mv` work for pathnames containing spaces. That should cover normal cases, unless you have pathnames containing newlines or other unusual characters.

You might prefer moving directories first, to avoid warnings from `find` when it can't search in subdirectories it just moved. `-type d`:

```
find source -type d --mindepth 1 -cmin -200 -cmin +100 -exec echo mv -v "{}" target \;
```

As always: dry-run (`echo`) first to simulate what would happen. [Here is a similar discussion from Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14345714/recursively-moving-all-files-of-a-specific-type-into-a-target-directory-in-bash)

Comment: Thank you @grebneke and all for replying so promptly. Ok, that find works well, so please now how do I incorporate it into a mv command, or other way of moving the files and directories?

Comment: @HarryWeston - added some general guidelines on moving the data

Answer (score 4):

As @grebneke suggested, following command with help to move files

```
find . ! -path . -cmin -200  -cmin +100 -exec echo mv -v {} /tmp/  \;
```

This is also dry run because we have used `echo`, if output looks good then you can remove echo and move files.

**find command explanation**

- `.`  where to look
- `! -path .` exclude current directory
- `-cmin -200` 200 minutes ago
- `-cmin +100` 100 minutes ago
- `-exec` Execute  command
- `{ }` The string { } replaced by the matches file name
- `\;`  Needs to be there as it tells the end of arguements provided to `-exec` variable

Comment: As far as I can tell, there's no reason to create a new shell for each invocation of `mv` here. Doing so will be far less efficient over a large number of files than just calling `mv` directly.

Comment: @ChrisDown thanks, what would be alternate solution? `xargs` ?

Comment: Why not just `-exec echo mv {} /tmp \;`?

Comment: @ChrisDown hmm, let me test that..

Comment: @ChrisDown thanks.. mate. just updating in answer..

Comment: Thank you again for all the answers, very much appreciated -- unfortunately I can mark only one as the answer, so I chose the first. I have done the job ok using find, as suggested, and realised that the timing was easy as I had not used the drive for sometime so I simply moved out everything from the day before, and that left me with just the backed up material.